# L'impact de l'emploi de la préposition « parmi » dans le choix de la préposition utilisée dans le renforcement du superlatif relatif ?

Tags: prépositions, lexique, partitif, superlatifs

> Le Canada est responsable de 1,6 % des émissions mondiales de GES,
>   mais les émissions par habitant sont **parmi** les plus élevées **du monde.** (ds. [*Le pétrole albertain plus polluant que tout le Québec*](https://www.lapresse.ca/actualites/environnement/201904/17/01-5222501-le-petrole-albertain-plus-polluant-que-tout-le-quebec.php),
>   LaPresse.ca, je souligne)

Hormis des tours plus figés ou après certains mots, j'apprends qu'on peut utiliser [au choix](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=au%20monde&id=5276) la préposition *à* ou *de* ([*au monde, du monde*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/monde/0)) pour le renforcement du superlatif relatif. Or on m'explique que :

> L’angle sous lequel les faits sont présentés est cependant quelque peu
>   différent. Le choix de la préposition *de* implique une relation «
>   partitive », d’un élément appartenant à un ensemble, alors que celui
>   de la préposition *à* met plutôt l’accent sur l’aspect « locatif »,
>   sur le lieu. L’emploi de la préposition *de* est à rapprocher de celui
>   de ***parmi*** ou ***d’entre***, tandis que la préposition *à* pourrait être
>   remplacée par ***dans*** ou ***en***, selon le contexte.
>
> [ *Banque de dépannage linguistique* (OQLF), « [Du monde, au monde](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=au%20monde&id=5276) », je souligne ]

- A-t-on l'impression que puisque la préposition *de* est assimilable
  dans ce contexte entre autres à la préposition *parmi*, que
  l'utilisation précédente de la préposition *parmi* dans la phrase
  fait double emploi ou peut-on m'expliquer sommairement comment on applique le concept de «
  relation partitive » avec l'idée du « monde » alors qu'on a « parmi
  les plus élevées » dans la phrase s'appliquant à la même idée ?

  > *...parmi les plus élevées **du**{ **parmi/d'entre** [celles d'ailleurs dans le] }  monde.* 
  >   *...parmi les plus élevées **au**{ **dans/en** [le] }  monde.*
- Peut-on discuter de la fréquence de l'emploi de l'une et l'autre des  prépositions *à/de* dans ce contexte, plus spécifiquement si possible quand on est en présence de la préposition *parmi* qui précède comme dans l'exemple ?

Comment: "parmi le monde" est incorrect : 'parmi' est suivi d'une liste (dénombrable) -- comme 'among' en anglais d'ailleurs.

Comment: Je n'utiliserais pas *à* dans cette phrase, mais je ne pense pas que le *parmi* qui précède en soit la raison. *Parmi les plus élevés au monde* me semble tout à fait possible dans d'autres contextes.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Probablement que la question n'est pas assez claire si tu dis que ce n'est pas _parmi_ qui t'empêcherais d'utiliser _à_ ici vu que cette préposition vaut pour _dans_ ou _en_ et qu'alors il n'y aurait pas double emploi (sous-jacent) par rapprochement avec _parmi_.

Answer (score 1):

Comme indiqué en commentaire, il est tout à fait convenable de dire "parmi les plus élevés au monde", en pratique du moins.

Cependant, comme on peut le lire dans l'extrait suivant, deux choses sont à noter :

1. L'emploi de "du monde" est plus correct dans le contexte donné,
2. Il n'y pas de lien entre l'emploi de "parmi" et le superlatif relatif à suivre.

> Spécialt. Du monde, Au monde, renforce un superlatif relatif. Le plus grand lac du monde. Ils sont les meilleurs amis du monde. Nous nous entendons le mieux du monde. C'est l'être qu'elle aime le plus au monde. « Est-ce que je vous dérange ? - Pas le moins du monde ». Le plus vieux métier du monde, la prostitution. Prov. **La plus belle fille du monde** ne peut donner que ce qu'elle a. • Du monde s'utilise également après un nom précédé de Tout. Il dit de vous tout le bien du monde. Tout l'amour du monde. **Après les pronoms Tout et Rien, avec les adjectifs Aucun, Seul et Unique, on dit Au monde**. Je donnerais tout au monde pour n'avoir pas fait cela. Je ne voudrais de cette maison pour rien au monde. Un joyau unique au monde.
>
> [ *Définition du CNRTL*, https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/monde/0 ]